# How can I use GMap.NET dll in delphi?

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, delphi-2010, gmap.net

I'm a C# programmer who use GMap.NET for C# for a long time!
Now I want to know if I can use its dll files in Delphi.
I've tried to import its dll files in a VCL Forms Application in Delphi EX3 and add GMapControl to a form. But I don't know how to use it now! For example GMapControl has lots of properties in C#. like Position, Zoom, etc. But now I can't see these properties in GMapControl that is imported into Delphi.

I'm looking for a way to use it in Delphi and if it's not possible, I would be glad to know this fact in order not to waste time on it anymore!
thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Assuming that the .net control is supplied in a .net assembly DLL, then there's no built-in way to host the control in Delphi. Realistically, you are looking at RemObjects Hydra to be able to host this in Delphi.

Comment: There are several ways to get a dotnet control in your Delphi application to work, but perhaps an easier way is to find something that's native to Delphi. Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/gmlibrary/ for example.

Comment: You could possibly get somewhere with the "Hydra" product from RemObjects, but going to a native library as Wouter suggests is a far better idea.

Comment: I agree with what @WarrenP said. Trying to force .net GUI controls into Delphi is something you do as final resort, when all else has failed.

Comment: Thanks everybody!According to your answers, it seems that I'd better not to waste time on it. Even the developer of GMap.NET told me that he doesn't have any idea of using GMap.NET in Delphi!